# BT136 TRIAC not closing on LOW signal to the MOC3021

Tags: opto-isolator, triac

I am trying to make an AC dimmer. I am following this schematics for my circuit,

[Circuit Link](https://www.engineersgarage.com/node/4812?i=923324)

[image]

as you can see in the below picture that I am able to turn the signal on after a short while of zero voltage

[image: enter image here]

The blue signal is from my micro- controller (I'm using a PIC18f45 instead of an arduino) to the moc3021  and yellow signal is from the 12 V AC (I am trying to control 220V AC but this oscilloscope can't seem to read higher voltage so this is just to show that I am able to send a signal at zero voltage)

I am not able to dim the light buld. Even with that setup the bulb is still very bright. I tried shortening and lengthening the HIGH signal to the MOC but it doesn't seem to affect it

From what I have understood the moc3021 is a random phase triac driver meaning that I should be able to open and close the gate of at any time of the wall AC phase. The triac should have turned off when the signal turned low but instead the bulb is still very bright.

Am I missing a concept here ? what should I do for it to turn off when the signal goes low?

Comment: Triacs, in general, cannot be turned off; they turn off on their own when the voltage between MT1 and MT2 crosses zero, but they can't be turned off outside of that (without some really hefty drive circuitry).

Comment: but can they be turned on at anytime of the phase?

Comment: I believe so, yes.

Comment: Please do not use "closed" or "open" for active devices.  "Closed" like a valve means it's **not** conducting; "closed" like a switch means it **is** conducting.  The same ambiguity exists for "open".  Use "on" and "off", or "conducting" and "not conducting".

Comment: Triacs turn off when the **current** drops below the holding current. In this case it's quite close to where the **voltage** between MT1 and MT2 crosses zero.

Comment: @Huisman True, I suppose I was wrong above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the concept here, yes.  Triacs (and SCRs) have a strong positive feedback effect internally: they can be turned on with gate current, but not off.

To regulate power to a light bulb, you need to change *when* the gate is turned on -- the later in the half-cycle that you turn on the gate, the less power the bulb gets, and the dimmer it gets.

Note that this all may not work with LED and CFL bulbs -- I've kind of lost track of the magic that they put in between the base and the active elements, but I know they don't necessarily like dimmers.

Comment: I am trying it on a good old incandescent bulb. So what i am doing is the opposite, i should not turn on the voltage right after zero cross. but instead wait and then turn on . does it only need a very short pulse to keep it on ?

Comment: @Jack Yes, the pulse only needs to be long enough to turn it on, after which it remains on until the current (not, actually, the voltage; I was wrong earlier, oops) goes to zero.

Comment: will do some testing, I will come back for an update :)

Comment: Got back from testing and yes, it now works, it seems that i misunderstood how triacs works. Thank you .

Comment: I'm glad we could help.